# Justify items to center but keeping space-between attribute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would need to know how can I place elements to center while still maintaining the `justify-content: space-between` attribute?

Roughly something like this:

[image]

The red items need to be aligned with `justify-content: space-between` so they would "touch" the black lines. If there if only one item on the line, it would be aligned to center.

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-basis: calc(50% - x)` where x is half the distance between every two elements in the same row, then use `margin:auto` on the last element if it is the only element in that row (i.e. if it is the last element and has an odd order). I am using `20px auto 0px auto` so that I don't override the top margin I have set in the previous rule.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex div {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 50px);
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #D85E5E;
}

.flex div:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin:20px 0;
}  


.item {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.item:only-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```